# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS freezing at boot/startup

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, nvidia, freeze

I was doing some machine learning with Nvidia GPU when I ran into an error that was CUDA related. I decided to reboot my computer to fix the error but when booting Ubuntu, my screen freezes. I opened up the GRUB console to see what was happening and it was freezing at

```
Starting GRUB failed boot detection
Starting Authorization Manager
```

I tried to reboot again, it was recovering journal and clearing orphaned inodes until this popped up

```
/dev/sda8: clean, 2757878/46759936 files 155438410/187020544  blocks
```

And then froze there, only being able to manually reboot my computer.

I then tried launching in recovery mode :`Linux 5.8.0-63-generic`
In the grub loader, this starts ubuntu, assigns my user, mounts, and flushes my journal to persistent storage, it outputs `started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status` and then it freezes.
Doing it a second time caused it to get past that and output `Finished Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.` at which point nothing happens and I can't do anything.

I have also tried following this article : https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/

I edited the params with `nomodeset` and this ended up freezing at

```
[   OK   ] Started Hostname Service. 
systemd-hostnamed.service
```

Trying `nouveau.noaccel=1` ends up freezing on

```
[   OK   ] Started Authorization Manager.
systemd-user-sessions.service
polkit.service
          Starting Modem Manager...
          Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
          Starting Hostname Service...
```

Finally replacing `quiet splash` with `noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll` causes a black screen where nothing comes up after waiting 10 minutes.

An important note is that I had an update that I hadn't applied yet.

Other things I have tried:

1.) Booting into rescue target (`systemd.unit=rescue.target`)

````
Result: Freezes at ```failed to start show plymouth boot screen```
````

2.) Booting into emergency target(`systemd.unit=emergency.target`)

```
Result: Message displays saying I am in emergency mode and asks for root password for 
maintenance or press Control-D To continue. Blinking typing sign shows up for a second and 
then dissapears. I cannot type or press Control-D and seems to be frozen.
```

I then finally tried booting with `init=/bin/sh` and I have access to an shell finally but I am at a loss at what I should start doing.

The top of my shell states `/bin/sh: 0: can't access tty: job control turned off`

I remounted my drive, and ran `systemctl enable debug-shell.service` which created a sym link and is supposed to give me access to a root shell from an early point so I can check systemctl logs. I also tried running `fsck -f /` and `fsck -f /dev/sda8` to check my disk but it said

```
/dev/sda8 is mounted
e2fsck: cannot continue, aborting.
```

I reboot and boot in using the normal ubuntu and after pressing `ctrl + alt + f9`, a root shell comes up with my user but I only have a few seconds before it freezes entirely again

What is causing this issue and any suggestions on fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

I went in and booted with `init=/bin/sh` again and ran these commands to uninstall Nvidia Drivers

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf # This command did not work as file doesn't exst
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

I rebooted normally and it got to the Ubuntu log in screen, with screen zoomed in but that is something that will require installation of nvidia drivers again.